# How will Prolog interpret this?

Tags: prolog

How will prolog interpret this expression?

```
a(R) :- b(R,S), b(S,R).
```

Does this mean that a(R) will only return true if both b(R,S) and b(S,R) are true?

Comment: Yes, the comma is a quite similar to a *logical and*.

Comment: It's better to say "a(R) will SUCCEED if both b(R,S) and b(S,R) SUCCEED (in that order)"? Because  there is no return value as such, there is only success (meaning the goal could be labeled true and variable values can be picked up, in this case, in `R`) or failure (meaning the goal could NOT be labeled true and there are no variable values). Note also that `a(R)` can succeed by other clauses, so no "only" here unless this is the only clause.

Answer (score 4):

> `a(R)` will only return true if both `b(R,S)` and `b(S,R)` are true?

**Yes**. The comma is a logical and. The rule:

> ```
> a(R) :- b(R,S), b(S,R)
> ```

can thus be explained as:

"*`a(R)` holds given there exists an `S` such that `b(R, S)` holds, and `b(S, R)` holds*".

If for example you have a dataset like:

```
b(a, c).
b(a, d).
b(c, a).
b(b, c).
```

Then it will succeed for `a(a)`, since `b(a, c)` holds and `b(c, a)`. But it will not succeed for `a(b)`, since `b(b, c)` holds, but not `b(c, b)`.

Comment: The comma is a _logical and_ for a very limited interpretation of Prolog code. `a, b` very easily becomes "a, and if it succeeds, then b" which is more like the short-circuited "and" of procedural languages.

Comment: @User9213 Well, yes, the order of calling (the control) is traditionally done top-down, left-to-right. But you can backtrack, so it's a bit more than in procedural languages. If you replace the ','  everywere by a '->', you are indeed getting procedural. (It is one of my wishes that control be more flexible ... along those lines: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277289331_The_Essence_of_Strategic_Programming